# How to create custom keyboard shortcuts in Gnome with wayland?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, wayland

My main target: bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> as <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> buttons.

I have tried to create shortcuts with default gnome shortcut adder via settings, but with this approach you can only bind shortcut to execute command and it's the main problem (Wayland can't emulate keyboard presses via command)

What can I do?